# Array list index of returns no package identifier

Tags: android

I have `ArrayList<String> rdItems = new ArrayList<String>();`

then `rdItems.add(0, str);` when something has happened.

then when i do this,

```
if (rdItems.contains(str)) {
    Toast.makeText(ma, str, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    Toast.makeText(ma, rdItems.indexOf(str), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

it enters the condition and toasts the value of `str` but not the index of it from rdItems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The version of `Toast.makeText()` that receives an int as the second parameter is expecting a **resource id** (something like `R.string.myresource`). It is not meant to be used to display an arbitrary integer value.

You should convert the int value to a string, something like:

```
Toast.makeText(ma, String.valueOf(rdItems.indexOf(str)), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

Comment: Yeah, i missed that part that indexOf method returns int. thank you so much.